# Interesting probability question

Tags: probability

Crates of eggs are inspected  for faults by randomly removing 4 of the in succession and examining them. If  all 4 eggs pass the test the crate ships;otherwise rejected. What is the probability that a crate will ship
that contains 150 eggs, which have 10 have blemishes.
Pr(bad egg)=10/150=1/15
Pr(bad egg| 2)=9/149
...
(1/15)*(9/149)*(8/148)*(7/147)

Is this correct

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [hypergeometric distribution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hygepdf.html). It gives the

> probability of drawing exactly $x$ of a possible $K$ items in $n$
>   drawings without replacement from a group of $M$ objects,

accounting for all the different possible ways of drawing the $x$ items given that there are $n$ items being drawn. In your case, $x = n = 4$, $K = 10$, and $M = 150$, where $K$ is the number of items in the set that are deemed failures and $M$ is the total number of items. The result $1.0365 \times 10^{-5}$ is the probability that the crate does not ship, so $1 - 1.0365\times 10^{-5} = 0.999$ is the probability that the crate does ship.

Comment: I thought of using it. It was.not in that section. You can only use conditional prob or ithe product rule if it applies

Comment: Not sure if either applies here. You're just looking at the number of ways to choose 4 items out of 150 such that all four are failures. This is just combinatorics. The number of ways to choose 4 out of the 10 items with blemishes is (10 choose 4). The number of ways that none of the remaining 146 items have blemishes is (140 choose 0) = 1. The number of ways both of these can happen is their product. The total number of ways that you could choose 4 items from 150 is (150 choose 4). The fraction gives you the probability of failure and 1 minus the fraction gives you the probability of success.

Comment: Please up-vote/accept my answer if you found it helpful.